# Type Error global.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor in NUXT

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, socketcluster

I am trying to use [THIS](https://github.com/happilymarrieddad/vue2-socketcluster) library on the client side as a plugin  When I npm run dev the client, I get this error
[image]

My `vue2socketcluster.js` file inside the plugins folder looks like this

```js
import Vue2Socketcluster from 'vue2-socketcluster'

Vue.use(Vue2Socketcluster,{
  hostname:"localhost",

  secure:true,
  propName:"socket" // Defaults to socket - so if you want vm.$soc you would change this to "soc"
})
```

and nuxt config had an entry for plugins

```js
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/vue2socketcluster'
],
```

Any direction will be super appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by setting server side rendering to false. Thank you

```js
plugins: [
  { src: '~/plugins/sc', mode: 'client' }
],
```

Comment: Updated towards `mode: 'client'` since it's now the default to use.